# What is the difference between mymethod(i) and mymethod(&i) in C?

Tags: c, pointers, address-operator

I was wondering what the difference in is between calling a method like :

```
int x;
mymethod(x);
```

and

```
mymethod(&x);
```

Comment: the same as between `car` and `garage` (:joke:)

Comment: @n00b: I don't get the joke...

Comment: If you need more information, just google for "C pointers". They will explain x, *x and &x :)

Comment: @Cody thats not **where i parked** my **car** :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because C always does call-by-value, **if you want the function to be able to change the x** inside the function itself, you have to pass the address of x.

```
mymethod(x);
```

**will pass x**, for example if x is 2, you could as well have written `mymethod(2)`

```
mymethod(&x)
```

**will pass the address to x**. Now the method can **change the value** stored at that address, so after the function is completed, the actual value of x might have been changed.

Now you can also declare a pointer:

```
int* y; //y is now a pointer to a memory address
y = &x; //y now points to the memory address of x;
*y = 5; will set the "value found at the address y" to 5, thus will set x to 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

`mymethod(x)` passes in the integer `x` as a parameter. `mymethod(&x)` passes in the address in memory of `x`. If you required a pointer-to-int as an argument, then you would use the second one.

Answer (score 0):

In few words, when you declare a pointer, you precede it by an asterisk:

```
int *ptr;
```

When you pass `&x` instead of `x`, you are passing the memory address.

Please, read [this useful introduction to the pointers](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch1x.htm).

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In the line:
int x;

you allocate a piece of memory in the size of "int".
for this explanation we will assume the size of int is 4 bytes (it might not be 4 bytes).

so after the line "int x;" there are 4 bytes in the memory assigned to "x".
the value of "x" is inside these 4 bytes:
for example, if x=4 then it will look in the memory like this:
[0, 0, 0, 4] or in binary [0000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000010].
(In real life it could also be [4, 0, 0, 0], but I won't get into that).

so the **VALUE** of x is 4.

But lets say I want the address of "x", where it is placed in the memory.
This is where the operator "&" comes into play, using this operator I request **the address** of x.

so if [0, 0, 0, 4] starts at the location "0x12341234" in the memory, &x will return that (0x12341234).
Now, if I want to store the address in a variable, this variable's type is not "int", but it is something that **points to the address** of int which is being marked as "int*".

So:

int x = 4; // <-- allocates memory of 4 bytes and fills its value with the number 4.
int* pointer_to_x = &x; // <-- pointer_to_x points to the address where x is located in the memory.

if there is a method declared like so:
void mymethod(int x) than we pass THE VALUE of x, so the method is being called mymethod(x).

if there is a method declared like so:
void mymethod(int* x) than we pass a POINTER to the address of x, so the method is being called mymethod(&x).

It is really the tip of the iceberg, and I really tried to keep it simple as I could, so if you have further questions, just ask!

There are also terms called "by value" and "by reference" but you still need to understand better the difference between int and int* and than "by value" and "by reference" will be quite natural.